# Can "la luz" be plural (lights) as well as singular (light)?

Tags: traducción, plurales, número-gramatical

Duolingo accepts "the lights went out" as a translation of "se fue la luz"

But shouldn't it be "the light went out" (singular)?

I checked what https://www.translate.com/ would say about it. According to that site, the phrase "the light went out" corresponds to "se fue la luz", but it translated the plural form, "the lights went out"  as "apagaron las luces"

I would expect it to be:

> The light went out = se fue la luz
>
> The lights went out = se fue las luces

Logic and/or consistency seem to be missing in both places.

Comment: Creo que la diferencia está en que "las luces" se refiere a la iluminación, pero "la luz" se refiere al suministro eléctrico en general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Luz* has of course a plural. Mind that the verb tense is correct in "*se fue las luces*", but you need to use *fueron*, 3rd form of plural, instead on the 3rd form of singular *fue*.

> Se fue la luz (or la X), pero (ella) ya volverá.

Third person singular

> Se fueron las luces (or las XXXs), pero (ellas) ya volverán.

Third person plural

One of the reasons I think you might have seen that difference in *fueron* and *apagaron* (apart from the fact that language translations are not a mathematical process) is that *la luz* would address to a single source of light (that lamp on my desk or in my room, for example). *Las luces* would address to several sources of light, like in an office, that might be less prone to go out but to be turned off instead.

Nevertheless, in all the street lamps went out at the same time you could say bot *se fue la luz* (the source of powers is missing or out_ and *Se fueron las luces* (the street lamps went out).

Comment: This question got downvoted. Can anyone point to things thst might not be accurate or that could be improved or explained better? Thanks.

Comment: No se explicarte gramáticamente por qué, pero toda mi vida cuando se va la energía electrica, hemos dicho `se fue la luz`, y tengo experiencia de los apagones en Cuba

Comment: También luz puede ser un incontable, como lo es en inglés en contextos parecidos (*there's/'re hardly any light(s) here*, singular incontable, se considera la luz producida por las luces, plural contable que considera cada fuente de luz como individual)

Comment: Y como dice @JaimeCruz `Se fueron las luces (or las XXXs), pero (ellas) ya volverán` por lo menos a mi me suena super raro.

Comment: @guifa si parece una posibilidad, investigaré acerca de eso

Comment: @EmilioGort, raro? buscan en google _"se fueron las luces"_. Yo lo he visto [incluso en el periódico](http://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento-2013/MAM-814768). Será diferencia regional, pero también yo puedo decir que he oído las dos formas toda mi vida. [Montones de ejemplos](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22se+fueron+las+luces%22+rae)

Comment: 10 results (0.37 seconds), son montones en la web?, pero si tienes razón, en realidad no se especíifica en la pregunta si es el fluído eléctrico  o se habla de luces de lámparas.

Comment: @EmilioGort, son pocos, pero me parecen suficientes para mostrar que es una forma que se usa en el español hablado y escrito. Simplemente quería entender los downvotes de esta respuesta y por qué otra gente del sitio la encuentra "not useful". Se ve que es por una diferencia regional. El problema es que ahora no puedo intentar explicar que es una expresión válida sin parecer _escocido_ por los downvotes.

Comment: @Diego para remover mi downvote necesito le hagas un edit, pq jo me deja el sistema

Comment: Gracias, pero no es por los puntos. Sólo quería entender por qué más de uno pensaba que era una mala respuesta. Creo no hay nada que quiera cambiar en mi respuesta. :-)

Comment: He leído algunos de los ejemplos que da Google. Por lo general, *se fueron las luces* se utiliza cuando nos referimos a algunas luces concretas, mientras que *se fue la luz* es general. Además, si usamos *luz* como sinónimo de *suministro eléctrico*, es siempre singular, claro, por ser incontable.

Answer (score 7):

When you say, *Light went out*, translated to spanish is *Se fue la luz* and means there were a cut in the energy system, it is *se fue* because there is no energy, in Spanish *luz* and *light* means both electricity and light.

*Lights went out* literally translated is *Se **fueron** las luces*, *fueron* has to be plural too. This translation sounds a little bit weird in in Spanish -I imagine some lights running away-. The meanings of this is that the lights were turned off, so the translation has to be "Se apagaron las luces".

You can translate the first phrase as *Se apagó la luz* if you want to mean that a lamp got turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not usually when we want to refer to electic power. When I think of "luces" I think of the lights they put on stages at concerts or venues. "Se fueron las luces" gives me the feeling that the lights moved out of sight, while "se apagaron las luces" means they were turned off.

Note that we also say "se fue la luz" when we want to say that there's a blackout or that the power in a building went out.